# Will big size of the app reject users from using it?

Tags: android

The games prevent this by making the core app only which then downloads the graphics and other stuff on the first run.

But what about the apps which have heavy animations and which final size is around 100MB (maybe even 200MB)? Regardless of the app's quality, does size matter? Do big apps reject users from downloading it?

And the final question, is there a way to download the heavy stuff to a place where a user will not be able to delete it? I think it's not possible, but I'd rather ask the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is my personal experience and thoughts:

If you are designing something astonishing and it costs even few hundred MBs on my phone, so i really wouldn't mind to give a try. Since new phones, processors and high storage capacities are continuously evolving and appearing in consumers' hands, so how can we expect applications to remain the same (tiny) in size? Let them grow (but not without any valid reason), and people would still try/buy it :)

Go-Go-Gadget!  :D

P.S. regarding your second question. Its not a good practice to make the user suffer unknowingly and crave for space. Anyhow, you may still achieve this by downloading your data on SD card but not in the cache folder, but somewhere in your own defined directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

personally i would never install such an app unless i would really need it (which is unlikely). I don't like apps which use more than 10MB, except for really good games (That's not a limitation of my phone). I think that such big apps tend to be overloaded with things I don't essentially need for using them, thus slowing down the phone and ruin battery life. For an overall good user experience it is a good idea to use the [Android design guideline](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html). Users will easily find out how to work with the app and the size of the app will be small.

I don't think animations should use so much space. Have you considered rendering them instead of storing them?

The majority of devices is not suitable for such big apps, thus if you are planning to sell this app, your potential market is just a tiny fraction of all android users.

Comment: What do you mean "Have you considered rendering them instead of storing them"?

Comment: Technically everything you can do on screen with pre-defined UI-widgets or animations can be calculated on the device. It uses more CPU power but usually needs less space